# How do I create a CURD application using ionic 2 and DynamoDB‎

Tags: ionic2, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create an ionic2 application with Amazon DynamoDB‎‎, any suggestions on how I can proceed or if I could find a sample application will be helpfull
I am following this aws-cognito-ionic2 by aws labs to get started, the link is here, however connection to DynamoDB‎ is not clear
Please this github [link](https://github.com/vbudilov/aws-cognito-ionic2) to view my starter

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you've already seen this, but worth a shot. Looked into https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-connect-to-dynamodb-directly/15215 ?